# OpenShift Origin asks for credentials

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, openshift-origin

I had a cluster OpenShift with a master and a node. Today, it doesn't work anymore, OpenShift continously asks me the credentials, the following is the command and the output:

```
[root@openshift-master ~]# openshift start master --config=openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml
W0615 07:26:00.645598    2554 start_master.go:270] assetConfig.loggingPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view aggregated container logs in the console
W0615 07:26:00.645661    2554 start_master.go:270] assetConfig.metricsPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view cluster metrics in the console
I0615 07:26:01.123879    2554 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.
I0615 07:26:01.220499    2554 genericapiserver.go:81] Adding storage destination for group 
I0615 07:26:01.220532    2554 genericapiserver.go:81] Adding storage destination for group extensions
I0615 07:26:01.220552    2554 start_master.go:383] Starting master on 0.0.0.0:8443 (v1.2.0-rc1-dirty)
I0615 07:26:01.220556    2554 start_master.go:384] Public master address is https://192.168.1.181:8443
I0615 07:26:01.220568    2554 start_master.go:388] Using images from "openshift/origin-<component>:v1.2.0-rc1"
I0615 07:26:01.690075    2554 run.go:61] Started etcd at 192.168.1.181:4001
I0615 07:26:01.798909    2554 run_components.go:204] Using default project node label selector: 
W0615 07:26:02.300146    2554 controller.go:297] Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to &{{ } {kubernetes  default  a7bc6c6c-23d3-11e6-a479-06337000002a 8 0 2016-05-27 08:24:24 +0200 CEST <nil> <nil> map[] map[]} [{[{192.168.1.181 <nil>}] [] [{https 8443 TCP} {dns 53 UDP} {dns-tcp 53 TCP}]}]}
I0615 07:26:02.455421    2554 master.go:262] Started Kubernetes API at 0.0.0.0:8443/api/v1
I0615 07:26:02.455465    2554 master.go:262] Started Kubernetes API Extensions at 0.0.0.0:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1
I0615 07:26:02.455472    2554 master.go:262] Started Origin API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oapi/v1
I0615 07:26:02.455477    2554 master.go:262] Started OAuth2 API at 0.0.0.0:8443/oauth
I0615 07:26:02.455482    2554 master.go:262] Started Web Console 0.0.0.0:8443/console/
I0615 07:26:02.455487    2554 master.go:262] Started Swagger Schema API at 0.0.0.0:8443/swaggerapi/
I0615 07:26:04.512392    2554 run_components.go:199] DNS listening at 0.0.0.0:53
I0615 07:26:04.512442    2554 start_master.go:527] Controllers starting (*)
I0615 07:26:04.749125    2554 nodecontroller.go:143] Sending events to api server.
I0615 07:26:04.751339    2554 replication_controller.go:208] Starting RC Manager
I0615 07:26:04.752209    2554 horizontal.go:120] Starting HPA Controller
I0615 07:26:04.752554    2554 controller.go:211] Starting Daemon Sets controller manager
W0615 07:26:05.100389    2554 nodecontroller.go:671] Missing timestamp for Node openshift-node1. Assuming now as a timestamp.
W0615 07:26:05.100409    2554 nodecontroller.go:671] Missing timestamp for Node openshift-node2. Assuming now as a timestamp.
I0615 07:26:05.101485    2554 event.go:211] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"openshift-node1", UID:"openshift-node1", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RegisteredNode' Node openshift-node1 event: Registered Node openshift-node1 in NodeController
I0615 07:26:05.101522    2554 event.go:211] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"openshift-node2", UID:"openshift-node2", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RegisteredNode' Node openshift-node2 event: Registered Node openshift-node2 in NodeController
F0615 07:26:05.158602    2554 master.go:93] Failed to get supported resources from server: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
I0615 07:26:05.221398    2554 endpoints_controller.go:283] Waiting for pods controller to sync, requeuing rc default/php-apache
I0615 07:26:05.221502    2554 endpoints_controller.go:283] Waiting for pods controller to sync, requeuing rc default/redis-slave
```

The yaml configuration file is this:

```
admissionConfig:
  pluginConfig: null
apiLevels:
- v1
apiVersion: v1
assetConfig:
  extensionDevelopment: false
  extensionScripts: null
  extensionStylesheets: null
  extensions: null
  loggingPublicURL: ""
  logoutURL: ""
  masterPublicURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443
  metricsPublicURL: ""
  publicURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443/console/
  servingInfo:
    bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:8443
    bindNetwork: tcp4
    certFile: master.server.crt
    clientCA: ""
    keyFile: master.server.key
    maxRequestsInFlight: 0
    namedCertificates: null
    requestTimeoutSeconds: 0
controllerLeaseTTL: 0
controllers: '*'
corsAllowedOrigins:
- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.1.181:8443
- localhost
disabledFeatures: null
dnsConfig:
  allowRecursiveQueries: false
  bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:53
  bindNetwork: tcp4
etcdClientInfo:
  ca: ca.crt
  certFile: master.etcd-client.crt
  keyFile: master.etcd-client.key
  urls:
  - https://192.168.1.181:4001
etcdConfig:
  address: 192.168.1.181:4001
  peerAddress: 192.168.1.181:7001
  peerServingInfo:
    bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:7001
    bindNetwork: tcp4
    certFile: etcd.server.crt
    clientCA: ca.crt
    keyFile: etcd.server.key
    namedCertificates: null
  servingInfo:
    bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:4001
    bindNetwork: tcp4
    certFile: etcd.server.crt
    clientCA: ca.crt
    keyFile: etcd.server.key
    namedCertificates: null
  storageDirectory: /root/openshift.local.etcd
etcdStorageConfig:
  kubernetesStoragePrefix: kubernetes.io
  kubernetesStorageVersion: v1
  openShiftStoragePrefix: openshift.io
  openShiftStorageVersion: v1
imageConfig:
  format: openshift/origin-${component}:${version}
  latest: false
imagePolicyConfig:
  disableScheduledImport: false
  maxImagesBulkImportedPerRepository: 5
  maxScheduledImageImportsPerMinute: 60
  scheduledImageImportMinimumIntervalSeconds: 900
kind: MasterConfig
kubeletClientInfo:
  ca: ca.crt
  certFile: master.kubelet-client.crt
  keyFile: master.kubelet-client.key
  port: 10250
kubernetesMasterConfig:
  admissionConfig:
    pluginConfig: null
  apiLevels: null
  apiServerArguments: null
  controllerArguments: null
  disabledAPIGroupVersions: {}
  masterCount: 1
  masterIP: 192.168.1.181
  podEvictionTimeout: 5m
  proxyClientInfo:
    certFile: master.proxy-client.crt
    keyFile: master.proxy-client.key
  schedulerConfigFile: ""
  servicesNodePortRange: 30000-32767
  servicesSubnet: 172.30.0.0/16
  staticNodeNames: null
masterClients:
  externalKubernetesKubeConfig: ""
  openshiftLoopbackKubeConfig: openshift-master.kubeconfig
masterPublicURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443
networkConfig:
  clusterNetworkCIDR: 10.128.0.0/14
  externalIPNetworkCIDRs: null
  hostSubnetLength: 9
  networkPluginName: ""
  serviceNetworkCIDR: 172.30.0.0/16
oauthConfig:
  alwaysShowProviderSelection: false
  assetPublicURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443/console/
  grantConfig:
    method: auto
  identityProviders:
  - challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: claim
    name: anypassword
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider
  masterCA: ca-bundle.crt
  masterPublicURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443
  masterURL: https://192.168.1.181:8443
  sessionConfig:
    sessionMaxAgeSeconds: 300
    sessionName: ssn
    sessionSecretsFile: ""
  templates: null
  tokenConfig:
    accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 86400
    authorizeTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 300
pauseControllers: false
policyConfig:
  bootstrapPolicyFile: policy.json
  openshiftInfrastructureNamespace: openshift-infra
  openshiftSharedResourcesNamespace: openshift
  userAgentMatchingConfig:
    defaultRejectionMessage: ""
    deniedClients: null
    requiredClients: null
projectConfig:
  defaultNodeSelector: ""
  projectRequestMessage: ""
  projectRequestTemplate: ""
  securityAllocator:
    mcsAllocatorRange: s0:/2
    mcsLabelsPerProject: 5
    uidAllocatorRange: 1000000000-1999999999/10000
routingConfig:
  subdomain: router.default.svc.cluster.local
serviceAccountConfig:
  limitSecretReferences: false
  managedNames:
  - default
  - builder
  - deployer
  masterCA: ca-bundle.crt
  privateKeyFile: serviceaccounts.private.key
  publicKeyFiles:
  - serviceaccounts.public.key
servingInfo:
  bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:8443
  bindNetwork: tcp4
  certFile: master.server.crt
  clientCA: ca.crt
  keyFile: master.server.key
  maxRequestsInFlight: 500
  namedCertificates: null
  requestTimeoutSeconds: 3600
volumeConfig:
  dynamicProvisioningEnabled: true
```

This file is generated with this command:

```
openshift start master --write-config=openshift.local.config/master
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has your IP address changed?  That can often have this symptom since some of the default certificates are signed to the master IP.

Comment: The master IP isn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Your authentication session token has expired. You need to [`oc login`](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html#basic-setup-and-login) again.

The expiration time is controlled by the `oauthConfig.tokenConfig.accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds` field of your master config file.

Comment: are there any way to get unlimited time token for the CI/CD configuration on jenkins "Without expiration time I mean".